# run code/tasks in parallel from one python script?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

In this code i'm simply pulling from a queue and processing messages in a infinite loop. 
So, I pop the REST-based queue via API, parse the message, then send a sms message via Twilio and do it again and again and again infinitely.
I'm thinking of scale, so I want to maximize time and have this cycle run a few times simultaneously per script.

How can I transform this code to run 4 times simultaneously, without having to exec the file four times.

```
  .....
  var = 1 
  while var == 1 :  # This constructs an infinite loop
    try:
        queue = CHECKQ.queue("name_of_queue")
        msgs = queue.get(max=1, timeout=None)
        url =  msgs['messages'][0]['body']
        msgId =  msgs['messages'][0]['id']
        delMsg = queue.delete(msgId)
        number = "1"+url
        message = client.messages.create(to=number, from_="+15555555555",
                    body="Here's the link to install the controller -        
                    http://someapp.com")
    except (IndexError):
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: Have you looked into Python's [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html) module?

Comment: thank you, will apply it. probably answer this one myself.

Comment: epiphany ... concurrent loops

Answer (score 0):

I used a infinite loop mixed with multiprocessing, which is a lib that starts new sub processes instead of threads.

I developed 2 scripts/modules sendTxtMsg() and getWorkOffQueue().

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python 

    from lib.python.imports import *
    client = TwilioRestClient()

    def sendTxtMsg():
        try:
            work = getWorkOffQueue()
            number = json.dumps(work["phoneNumber"])
            message = client.messages.create(to=number, from_="+15555555555",
                      body="Here's the link to install the controller -                      
                      http://some.awesome.app/jelly")
            phonenumbersInsert(json.dumps(work))
        except(TypeError):
            pass
            print "Nothing on Queue"
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            log1.info(e)
```

---

and combined them into one module here below, which is executing the workflow multiple times simultaneously, in essence pulling off the queue with many arms and hands from one body...of code.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python                                                              

    from multiprocessing import Process
    from lib.python.imports import *

    def goGetEm():
        x = 1 
        while x == 1:
            sendTxtMsg()

     if __name__ == '__main__':
         Process(target=goGetEm).start()
         Process(target=goGetEm).start()
         Process(target=goGetEm).start()
         Process(target=goGetEm).start()
```